# Как автоматизировать UI и записывать логи?

Tags: javascript, macos, uiautomation

Использую JXA для автоматизации графического интерфейса.

Есть ли способ записывать в лог действия?

Могу автоматизировать кое-что используя JXA на OS X (10.13), но не могу записать в лог.

Что еще можно использовать для автоматизации UI и записи логов?

Comment: https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: thank you.

I have been reading this wiki back and forth couple last days. 

did you try something similar before?